# linux shell: for arg; do

Tags: bash, for-loop, sh, posix, bashism

Reading [LTP shell code](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/1b7128dac0ce8d32a33eb6b0087e0ca1cb812567/testcases/kernel/controllers/cgroup_fj/cgroup_fj_common.sh#L26-L28) it uses strange `for` loop syntax:

```
for arg; do
    TCID="${TCID}_$arg"
done
```

1. How does it takes arguments? I'd expect it loops over `$arg`, separating with `$IFS`, but when trying `$ arg="aa bb"; for arg; do echo $arg; done` and it prints nothing.
2. Is it a bashism?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a special way of handling command-line options using `for` loop.

It's equivalent to:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    TCID="${TCID}_$arg"
done
```

It's not specific to bash. It's defined in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04):

> **The for Loop**
>
> The **for** loop shall execute a sequence of commands for
> each member in a list of items. The **`for`** loop requires that the
> reserved words **`do`** and **`done`** be used to delimit the sequence of
> commands.
>
> The format for the **for** loop is as follows:
>
> ```
> for name [ in [word ... ]] do  
>    compound-list  
> done
> ```
>
> First, the list of words following `in` shall be expanded to generate a
> list of items. Then, the variable name shall be set to each item, in
> turn, and the `compound-list` executed each time. If no items result
> from the expansion, the `compound-list` shall not be executed. Omitting:
>
> ```
> in word ...
> ```
>
> shall be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> in "$@"
> ```